# Show phone screen on computer live

Tags: 8.0, pc

How can I see my phone screen from my pc, live? (phone is connected to that pc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be able to share your phone screen onto another device such as a PC you must have a Windows Phone device that is running an internal Microsoft build on the phone. Alternatively (and perhaps more likely) is that you would need a developer unlocked phone.

If you do manage to obtain a developer unlocked phone, you can use `Windows Phone Device Manager` that provides you with `Capture Phone Screen` functionality.

[A similar question to this was asked on the Microsoft forums and there is more detailed information provided here if you are interested](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp7-wppics/how-do-i-connect-and-mirror-my-phone-screen-on-a/1a2584bf-09c6-40d5-b190-4bcc87af9aee).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to project your actual device screen to any other device, including other phone or PC.

The possible overcomes are either to use an emulator (for demos, for example) or to use special cams with macro modus that would send the image live to your projector.

I have also had positive experience with a special overhead projector, that does not use the translumination for projection, but rather has a built-in camera: those projectors are used for showing scanned documents.

Comment: it's just that I was at a visit to Microsoft office and they did just that.. but they said the software is only for them.. I thought you may know an alternative.

Comment: I am aware of some custom internal firmware for WP7 that allowed projection to the screen, but I have never seen WP8 devices that had this functionality. Are you sure these were WP8 devices?

Comment: yep, it was wp8

Answer (score 0):

I use an IPEVO POV Camera.  $70 or so.  Available from Amazon - http://amzn.to/T7ify3 .

Works great with win8 and win7 both, and easily portable...